# Cant see what is wrong with query and warning message when executing access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

i've have the following query (below), that every time I click 'Run' i get this message

> 'Your query does not include the specified expression 'StudentNumber' as part of an aggregate function.'

```
SELECT results.StudentNumber, student.FirstName, student.LastName, 
 results.Result1, results.Result2, results.Result3, results.Overall, 
 ROUND(((AVG(results.Result1) + AVG(results.Result2) + 
         AVG(results.Result3)) / 3), 0) AS AverageMark 
FROM Results AS results 
  INNER JOIN Student AS student ON results.StudentNumber = student.StudentNumber
```

I don't understand what the issue is from the warning message, can anyone help shed any light or see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an aggregate function on **any** column (here: `AVG()`), then **all** columns must either be part of an aggregate function too, or specified in the `GROUP BY` clause.

If you want the average results per student, then all `student` columns should go into GROUP BY. But you cannot have detailed results **and** average results in one query - how would you expect the query output to look?

A working query should be e.g.

```
SELECT student.StudentNumber, student.FirstName, student.LastName, 
 ROUND(((AVG(results.Result1) + AVG(results.Result2) + 
         AVG(results.Result3)) / 3), 0) AS AverageMark 
FROM Results AS results 
  INNER JOIN Student AS student ON results.StudentNumber = student.StudentNumber
GROUP BY student.StudentNumber, student.FirstName, student.LastName
```